# How hide bottom toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uibarbuttonitem, photo-gallery

I have a problem showing the album a toolbar with the following buttons, previous and the new one appears in the bottom view. How can you hide this toolbar?

Thanks in advance.

[Album photo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7F4G.png)

```
 UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            controller.allowsEditing = YES;
            controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
            controller.delegate = self;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the toolbar you can use the following code . Here the toolBarName is the name of your toolbar.

```
toolBarName.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: It does not work, I put the code of the call to the uimagepickerController.

Comment: Are you using the toolbar or the navigation bar. If you are using the toolbar try the above code in viewWillDisappear()

Answer (score 0):

Include this in the viewWillAppear function:

```
self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
```

However, this is a Swift solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.Hope it helps..

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{

imagePickerController.delegate = self;

imagePickerController.allowsEditing = FALSE;

[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```